# Trouble with Camera settings

Tags: autofocus

My lens Nikon AF 85mm 1.8 will only focus at 22 otherwise I get a fEE flashing on the top display. Any suggestions? I use a D80.

Answer (score 0):

With the D80 you need to set the lens to f/22 and lock it there, then use the controls on the camera body to adjust aperture. This applies to any AF-D lens that has an aperture ring on the lens. Set it to the narrowest aperture and lock it with the little orange switch. **You can't adjust the aperture with the lens ring when it is attached to a D80, you must use the camera controls.**